# How do I write to a random access file?

Tags: c++, filestream

This code is supposed to write some items to the file but the file created has 0 bytes and is blank. 
I'm not really sure what's the problem.

I have no errors whatsoever. Also, can a random access file be .txt or does it have to be .dat?

The add function runs and adds the info error free but there is nothing in the file.

```
void add()
{
int hour, min, day, month, yr, snum, interNo,age;
string fname, lname, clinic, area, ex, li, type, sname, town, pay,problem, breed, gender;
char ans;
Intervention inte;


fstream InfoFile("JSPCA.dat", ios::in | ios::out |ios::app);
if (!InfoFile)
{
    cout << "Error -file could not be opened.";
}
else
{

    cout<<"Enter intervention number\n";
    ("Enter 0 to end input)\n");
    cin>>interNo;
    system("cls");


    InfoFile.seekp(sizeof(Intervention)*(interNo - 1));
    /* read record from file*/
    InfoFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&inte), sizeof(Intervention));

    if (inte.getClient().getInterventionNo() != 0)
    {

        cout << "inter # already contains information.\n";
    }
    else {

        /* create record */
        while (interNo != 0) {

            InfoFile.seekp(sizeof(Intervention)*(interNo - 1));

            InfoFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&inte), sizeof(Intervention));


            if (inte.getClient().getInterventionNo() != 0)
                cout << "inter # already contains information.\n";
            else {
                // user enters information, which is copied into file
                cout << "Enter name of clinic(Winchester or Caymanas)\n ";
                cin >> clinic;
                cout << "Enter lastname, firstname\n ";
                cin >> lname;
                cin >> fname;
                cout << "Please Address(Street#, Street Name, Town)\n";
                cin >> snum >> sname >> town;
                cout << "Enter Contact#:(area exchange line)\n";
                cin >> area >> ex >> li;
                cout << "Enter Animal Type\n";
                cin >> type;
                cout << "Enter Animal Breed\n";
                cin >> breed;
                cout << "Enter animal's gender\n";
                cin >> gender;
                cout << "Enter Animal problem\n";
                cin >> problem;
                cout << "Enter age of animal\n";
                cin >> age;
                cout << "Please enter letter for payment type:\n";
                cout << "Full=F\n";
                cout << "Contribution=C\n";
                cout << "Can't Pay=CP\n";
                cin >> pay;
                cout << "Enter date in format  dd mm yyyy\n";
                cin >> day >> month >> yr;
                cout << "Enter the time(hour minute\n)";
                cin >> hour >> min;
                //inte.getClient().getInterventionNo() == interNo;

                // set records for Client, address, TelNo, animal, date and time values
                inte.setClient(Client(fname, lname, pay, interNo, clinic));
                inte.setAddress(Address(snum, sname, town));
                inte.setTelNo(TelNo(area, ex, li));
                inte.setAnimal(Animal(type, breed, gender, problem, age));
                inte.setDate(Date(day, month, yr));
                inte.setTime(Time(hour, min));



                InfoFile.seekp(sizeof(Intervention)*(interNo - 1));
                InfoFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&inte), sizeof(Intervention));
            }
            system("cls");
            cout << "Enter new intervention number\n";
            cout<<"Enter 0 to end input";
            cin >> interNo;

        }
        }
}

}
```

Comment: "I have no errors whatsoever." ...

Comment: I meant run time errors..nothing wont run to the file

Answer (score 2):

There's at least three errors

1) You cannot do binary I/O when your object contains std::string. I'm guessing this is the case, you haven't posted the definitions of the object you are using. Bottom line is that you shouldn't just assume that you can do binary I/O on anything. You have to understand what kind of objects can be output using binary I/O. I'm guessing that yours can't.

2) If you want to do binary I/O you must open the file with with ios::binary

3) This is the reason you get an empty file. If the file is empty (or doesn't exist) then

```
InfoFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&inte), sizeof(Intervention));
```

will fail. After this no input or output operation will work until you clear the error (which you never do). So the following writes also fail and you end up with an empty file.

I think you have some studying to do on binary and random access I/O. This isn't close to being correct.

Comment: for the part where u said if the file is empty or doesnt exits..do u mean I have to write blank items to the file first?

Comment: No that's not necessary, but obviously any attempt to read from an empty file is going to fail. When that failure happens you should call `InfoFile.clear();` to clear the error before attempting anything else. Or you could just change your code so that you don't attempt to read from a location that doesn't exist. But as I said I think you have bigger problems than this.